# inner join returns only 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, join

let me sketch the situation a bit:
i have 2 tables: producten and reviews,
in producten i have multiple products stored, and in reviews i have stored all the reviews now while attemption to get the average of the ratings in the reviews table mysql only returns 1 row while i expect 2 rows back since i have 2 products.

the query im trying to use is:

```
SELECT p.*, CAST(AVG(r.rating) AS DECIMAL(2,1)) as waardering FROM `producten` as p INNER JOIN `reviews` as r ON p.id=r.product_id
```

i have also tried:

```
SELECT p.*, CAST(AVG(r.rating) AS DECIMAL(2,1)) as waardering FROM `producten` as p INNER JOIN `reviews` as r ON r.product_id=p.id
```

but this diddnt returned more then 1 row either.

could anyone please tell me why the query is only returning 1 row and not all the rows it finds inside the producten table?

also please feel free to tell me how i could increase this question if needed.

Comment: Do you have reviews for both products?

Comment: i do have that yes, and left join would also give me the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `GROUP BY p.id` at the end of your query so that you get the average per product, instead of the values in the "first" product's field with the average for all products.

Comment: Sidenote: It could just be me, but I don't see a difference between the two queries you provided in the question.

Comment: that worked! thanks, the difference is that i switched the p.id=r.product_id around in the hope that that would do the trick

Comment: Ah, now I see. No, that wouldn't affect anything; perhaps if one side or the other had some really funky stuff using session variables, but that would be a seriously unreliable query then.

Comment: though im kinda wondering how i could use full outer join now since if there is no review with a product that it just leaves that product away

Comment: You'd want a `LEFT JOIN` for that. MySQL doesn't actually support a `FULL` outer join anyway. Those have to be emulated with a combination of JOINs and a UNION (it's been a while since I had need for one, so I don't recall the specifics offhand).

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using AVG. It is going to group all the rows together as one row. You probably want to group by avg rating instead.

So if I had a table with two columns.. product name / rating... I would do like so:

```
select productname, avg(rating) from ratings group by productname
```